# Selenium TestReport did not show all the test results

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I ran 33 test cases. When i check the emailable-report.html file in reports directory . It shows only 25  test results.

Comment: Is there any error? provide more info i.e. code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using TestNG. I use it frequently, and I'm assuming you are looking at the top section with the numbers.

The first number is how many passed NOT the total. After that, it lists the number skipped, and then the number failed. If you add them all up, it should be 33. If it isn't then you aren't running all of your test cases.

[image]